# PCIe power from a Dell Optiplex 7020

Tags: power-supply, pci-express, dell-optiplex

We've just purchased a new Dell Optiplex 7020 to house a PCIe digitiser for use in scientific work. The PCIe card in question needs extra power in the from of a 6-pin 'PCIe' power cable.

Unfortunately the Dell we purchased doesn't seem to provide such a connector, so we're wondering what our options are. The PSU in question in rated at 290W and I *think* it should be able to power the PCIe device.

I've seen SATA-to-PCIe power cables like this , but I've read conflicting advice about whether or not using one of these is a good idea.

I'm sure there are other adapters we could use also.

The alternative is to buy a new PSU with explicit support for a 6-pin PCIe power cable. But I've also read that Dell PSUs/motherboards might use propriety connectors, and that a standard ATX PSU might not actually work.

I'm at a loss as to what to do. Can anybody please give me some advice?

Comment: It might be enough but if there isn't a power cable then the PSU can't be used.  Can you confirm your motherboard uses one of those propriety connectors?

Comment: I've just had a look and can only see a 4-pin Molex and an 8-pin Molex going from the PSU to the motherboard.

Comment: I can confirm that definitely some DELLs use proprietary connectors. So it must be checked. I agree with Ramhound - if there's no cable, do not use. Adapters like that are bad idea. OptiPlex line generally is for office use and rarely allows for expansion. Might be a good idea to check with seller if you can upgrade to different model that has the capability required.

Comment: The connectors you describe are not propriety.

Comment: In that case I'm guessing a new PSU is in order.  It's not like they're expensive!

Comment: Given the fact this digitizer is likely expensive I wouldn't want to connect it to a $25 cable that might work instead of a $75 PSU that will work.

Comment: BTW. Which variant? MT or SFF? It may not matter, but on the other hand - it may.

Comment: It's a MiniTower...